# Como transformar todos os itens de uma lista de strings em inteiros?

Tags: python

Eu tenho uma lista que contém "n" elementos do tipo `str`.
No entanto, eu preciso fazer com que esses elementos virem inteiros. Como posso fazer isso ?

Por exemplo,eu tenho essa lista aqui:

```
trechos = conteudo[2:len(conteudo)]
```

Acontece que eu não posso simplesmente forçar assim:

```
int(conteudo[2:len(conteudo)])
```

Pois o python dá erro. Como posso fazer pra transformar cada valor em inteiro ? E depois passar esses valores inteiros para uma nova lista ?

Comment: De novo a mesma pergunta? Você chegou a se dar o trabalho de ler o que te foi indicado na outra pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

```
items = ['1', '2', '-10', 'A', '1234567890']

for item in items:
    print('{} type: {}'.format(item, type(item)))

int_items = [int(value) for value in items if value.lstrip('-').isdigit()]

for item in int_items:
    print('{} type: {}'.format(item, type(item)))
```

#### output:

```
1 type: <class 'str'>
2 type: <class 'str'>
-10 type: <class 'str'>
A type: <class 'str'>
1234567890 type: <class 'str'>

1 type: <class 'int'>
2 type: <class 'int'>
-10 type: <class 'int'>
1234567890 type: <class 'int'>
```

#### [Funcionando no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/HfGOtT)

Answer (score 0):

Experimente isto:

```py
lista_inicial = ["12", "-4", "-232", "7", "1478"]

lista_final = [int(i) for i in lista_inicial]

print(lista_final)
```

Output:

```
[12, -4, -232, 7, 1478]
```